# Google Play Store Developer Console: Is it possible to get installs variable via API for my hosted app?

Tags: android, api, google-api, google-play

I have an Android application deployed on Google Play Store.

I am currently getting data like app installs from Google Play Store Developer Console (Statistics -> and just view the graph).

I want to be able to automatically get installs data for my App every day by running an API call and storing into my Database.

Is this possible using ONE OF googles APIs? 
This is very complex to understand how to get simple specific stuff from google because the explain everything in a general way.

What API do I need to register? 
Can someone give me the steps?

P.S: I use PHP or Javascript to sort out JSONs.

Answer (score 0):

You can using gsutil - follow this link https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil

https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/6135870?hl=en